# Input Format Validation

Tags: c++, linux

In linux, how to check that the input given is in uint8_t or uint16_t or uint32_t? How to compare the given input with them?

Comment: What kind of input are we talking about ? Through the console, a file, a GUI... ?

Comment: From file.  For example i read from file an input 745 how i check it is valid or not?

Comment: you have to narrow it down a bit. Many numbers could be all of the above.

Comment: @Umarniaz: Files are always considered byte streams.  From there you could read them as you need: as uint8_t, uint16_t or uint32_t.  Your question needs to be more specific

Comment: But i want to compare it not to read in uint8_t,uint16_t or uint32_t

Answer (score 0):

```
uint16_t value = boost::lexical_cast<uint16_t>(str);
```

It will throw a bad_cast exception if the input string cannot be converted.

Comment: Is there any other method to check this?

Comment: Yes.  It's programming, there are a hundred or a thousand other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by input a number read from a file or console, then just do an if-statement like this:

```
    #define max_uint8 (1<<8) - 1
    #define max_uint16 (1<<16) - 1
    #define max_uint32 (1<<32) - 1


    if(input > max_uint32) {
        // then it is greater than 32 bits
    } else if (input > max_uint16) {
        // then it is uint32
    } else if (input > max_uint8) {
        // then it is uint16
    } else {
        // then it is uint8
    }
```

Note: I assumed that your input will never be more than 32-bits, otherwise you will need to check this.

Comment: What if the input is greater then 32-bits?

Comment: @Umarniaz you will simply need to check this. Read your numbers in a 64-bit integer (i.e. long long), add one more value that is [(1 << 32) - 1] and adjust the if condition. I edited it above.